# How do I change the box shadow when clicking on buttons

Tags: javascript

Is there any way that I can separate the box shadow value into three parts.
For example, lets say I have clicked on the **400** button in the Shadow strength, and now I wanted to change the shadow direction by clicking on the appropriate buttons but the shadow strength should remain same.

I wanted to do this with simple way in Javascript and no plugins/libraries. I am able do separately for each button but how do I connect three of them together.

```
<div class="shadow-preview" style="padding:32px;margin:40px 20px;border:solid #89ACF1 1px;" id="shadow">
      <h2 style="padding:0 12px;display:block;margin:0;">Preview of the Box Shadow</h2>
      <div class="shadow-types" style="padding:12px">
        <h3 style="margin:0;padding:0 0 8px 0">Shadow strength</h3>
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('shadow').style.boxShadow = '0px 0px 10px #89ACF1';">100</button>
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('shadow').style.boxShadow = '0px 0px 60px #89ACF1';">200</button>
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('shadow').style.boxShadow = '0px 0px 90px #89ACF1';">300</button>
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('shadow').style.boxShadow = '0px 0px 120px #89ACF1';">400</button>
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('shadow').style.boxShadow = '0px 0px 250px 30px #89ACF1';">500</button>
      </div>
      <div class="shadow-direction" style="padding:12px">
        <h3 style="margin:0;padding:0 0 8px 0">Shadow position</h3>
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('shadow').style.boxShadow = '0px -12px 12px #89ACF1';">Top</button>
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('shadow').style.boxShadow = '20px 0px 12px #89ACF1';">Right</button>
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('shadow').style.boxShadow = '0px 12px 12px #89ACF1';">Bottom</button>
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('shadow').style.boxShadow = '-20px 0px 12px #89ACF1';">Left</button>
      </div>
      <div class="shadow-direction" style="padding:12px">
        <h3 style="margin:0;padding:0 0 8px 0">Shadow diagonal position</h3>
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('shadow').style.boxShadow = '20px -12px 32px #89ACF1';">Top Right</button>
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('shadow').style.boxShadow = '-20px -12px 32px #89ACF1';">Top Left</button>
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('shadow').style.boxShadow = '20px 12px 32px #89ACF1';">Bottom Right</button>
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('shadow').style.boxShadow = '-20px 12px 32px #89ACF1';">Bottom Left</button>
      </div>
      <div class="" style="padding:12px">
        <button style="background:blue;padding:12px;color:#fff;border:none;" type="button" name="button">Copy CSS Code</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Creating separate variable and combining together may help, but how do I do that

Comment: This would be much cleaner code if you separated the JS into its own script tag/JS file, and then used it to apply classes to affect the CSS (rather than directly setting styles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don’t want to work with CSS files and classes, you may put those attributes in button's dataset, and assign each attributes individually without conflicting.

```html
<!-- upon clicking, set the shadow weight to 250px, shadow spread to 30px -->
<button data-weight="250px" data-spread="30px">500</button>

<!-- upon clicking, set the shadow position x to -20px, shadow y position to -12px -->
<button data-x="-20px" data-y="-12px">Top Right</button>
```

Here's a working example:

```js
[...document.getElementsByClassName('shadow')].forEach(container => {
  const shadow = {
    x: '0px',
    y: '0px',
    weight: '0px',
    spread: '0px',
    color: '#89ACF1'
  };

  container.querySelectorAll(':is(.shadow-direction, .shadow-types) button').forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      // overwrite shadow properties based on button dataset
      Object.assign(shadow, button.dataset);
      container.style.boxShadow = `${shadow.x} ${shadow.y} ${shadow.weight} ${shadow.spread} ${shadow.color}`;
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="shadow shadow-preview" style="padding:32px;margin:40px 20px;border:solid #89ACF1 1px;">
  <h2 style="padding:0 12px;display:block;margin:0;">Preview of the Box Shadow</h2>
  <div class="shadow-types" style="padding:12px">
    <h3 style="margin:0;padding:0 0 8px 0">Shadow strength</h3>
    <button data-weight="10px" data-spread="0px">100</button>
    <button data-weight="60px" data-spread="0px">200</button>
    <button data-weight="90px" data-spread="0px">300</button>
    <button data-weight="120px" data-spread="0px">400</button>
    <button data-weight="250px" data-spread="30px">500</button>
  </div>
  <div class="shadow-direction" style="padding:12px">
    <h3 style="margin:0;padding:0 0 8px 0">Shadow position</h3>
    <button data-x="0px" data-y="-12px">Top</button>
    <button data-x="20px" data-y="0px">Right</button>
    <button data-x="0px" data-y="12px">Bottom</button>
    <button data-x="-20px" data-y="0px">Left</button>
  </div>
  <div class="shadow-direction" style="padding:12px">
    <h3 style="margin:0;padding:0 0 8px 0">Shadow diagonal position</h3>
    <button data-x="20px" data-y="-12px">Top Right</button>
    <button data-x="-20px" data-y="-12px">Top Left</button>
    <button data-x="20px" data-y="12px">Bottom Right</button>
    <button data-x="-20px" data-y="12px">Bottom Left</button>
  </div>
  <div class="" style="padding:12px">
    <button style="background:blue;padding:12px;color:#fff;border:none;" type="button" name="button">Copy CSS Code</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent!... One small request and sorry I could not mentioned it in my description that these section can be more than one, so I cannot duplicate it if there is a ID. How do I keep ClassName instead of id `id="shadow">`? I changed it to `document.getElementByClassName('shadow')` but not working.

Comment: The API you are looking for is [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)(plural), and it returns a HTMLCollection. In your case it would be `document.getElementsByClassName('shadow')[0]`

Comment: Yeah, I did that and it's working only for first block and even If I click on second block it is effecting first block only. `const shadowElement = document.getElementsByClassName('shadow')[0]`

Comment: I have updated my answer that supports multiple instances, please check!

Comment: I am not sure whether it is an error, If I don't click on any of the Shadow strength buttons and clicking directly on the "Shadow position" and "Shadow diagonal position" buttons then it is coming without any blur effect. So to fix this can we connect default value of 100?. 

But it is working perfectly fine if I click on the shadow strength buttons and moving to other buttons.

I am trying to add this "data-spread="0px"" into the x, and y position button but it's coming double the amount.